# JDK Installation Error in Windows 7

Tags: java

I'm new here, so mind me if I become impolite.

I'm having problem with my Java JDK installation.
I have a Toshiba laptop with 32-bit Windows 7 installed.

Recently, I format the C drive and re-installed Win 7.

Then, when I install the JDK on my newly installed Win 7 computer, an error pop-up.
This is the message:
***This installation package could not be opened. Verify that the package exists and that you can access it, or contact the application vendor to verify that this is a valid Windows Installer package.***

Before I format my hard disk, I have JDK 1.4, JRE, NetBeans, Eclipse, Servoy, Visual Studio 2008, MySQL and MS SQL Server. Everything worked fine in Windows 7 back then. And also, I can easily install all of these software after I install Win 7. Only the installation of JDK shows an error.
So, if I can't install JDK, I can't install NetBeans, Eclipse and Servoy also.

I've tried most websites online and they didn't give me one precise solution.
I've also tried Windows UAC settings and other administrative settings.
I'm not exaggerating myself, but I have three years experience of working together with Java. I haven't seen error like this.

**P.S.**
I've downloaded latest JDK version from Sun website. My old and new JDK installer packages show the same error. Weird!

Answer (score 3):

This sounds odd, try to verify the download is complete (file size/checksum) and then run Windows Update to ensure you've got the latest version of Windows Installer (I think it's used, but not 100% sure right now). Also, is there some specific reason for still using version 1.4 of the JDK (latest one is 1.7 after all)?

Comment: Yes, originally I have that error message with JDK 1.4. But, I downloaded version 1.7 and still having that error. And, most weird thing is, that error is only showing with JDK installation. Any other installation packages work fine, including Visual Studio and SQL Server. I'm out of ideas here.

Comment: Did you run the installer as admin? Right click, "Run as administrator". Just to be sure.

Comment: O'course, I did. I've tried to disable UAC and and run the package as administrator. But it's the same as before. I've even tried to install from Safe-mode.

Comment: Did you redownload the installer or is it from the old installation? Maybe you're somehow lacking access rights on the actual file? You could as well try to use tools such as **Process Monitor** from http://www.sysinternals.com/ trying to track down the source of the error message (e.g. which file access failed).

Comment: Yes, I thought of that, too. And I downloaded the latest installer from Sun website. But, error shows with the old and new installers both. I don't think I have problems with access right. I think there might be something wrong when I installed Win 7. I will try that Process Monitor you said. Thz a lot...!!!

Comment: Heys, guys... any other ways or ideas...!!! I've tried with Process Monitor n I've found any error relating to the installer package. Windows Update doesn't help too...!!! I'm definitely out of ideas.

Comment: Very weird. Read on Microsoft Answers (http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/this-installation-package-could-not-be-opened/49bed5b7-9569-44de-a14f-47f70e4da25e), that one possible solution would be creating a different user account to run the setup under (you can delete the account later on). This doesn't sound like a long time solution, but at least for now this should get you back working (if it works).

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you installed a JDK version that is compatible with your windows.

You have a 32-bit windows installed. You should look for a JDK version that is compatible

Oracle , the developer of JDK, issues different versions that work on different windows operating systems such as 64-bit and 86-bit windows and they are listed on there website for people to choose from. This is the link, http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Good luck !

Answer (score 1):

i think i found the solution. The problem is on your permissions.

*solution*

go to users...right click... go to properties...go to the security tab then click on advanced ..then enable inheritance then tick on (replace  all child object permision .....) click apply and ok